# Is regex possible in Pimcore workspace path?

Tags: pimcore

I have tree structured data about members in system. Fx. members objects are stored in `members` directory, and members projects objects are stored in members object. Key of member object is email of member.

So full paths to members project objects look like `members/user@mail.com/project`, `members/user2@email.com/project`, etc.

Now, I'm going to set full access to `/members` path, but I want to deny access to members projects objects. It woks fine when I set full access to `/members` workspace and deny access to specified path `/members/user@mail.com/project` but `user@mail.com` is a variable. Is it possible to do it by regex like `@^/members/(.*)/project@`? Is there any other solution?

Comment: That seems correct.

Comment: @tanaydin i guess it's incorrect, because even regex like `@^/members/(.*)` doesn't work

Comment: sorry haven't tried.. sorry for disturbing.